# cmake setup for cross library access using CMake OBJECT libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

#### cmake setup for cross library access

The tree for a minimal cmake project to illustrate my problem:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── app
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── main.cpp
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── lib1
    │   ├── a.cpp
    │   ├── a.h
    │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    └── lib2
        ├── b.cpp
        ├── b.h
        └── CMakeLists.txt
```

I want for a function in b.cpp to call a function in a.cpp. The following snippets show my failed attempt to do this. The `*.h` files are omitted as they just contain function signatures.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
project("cmake minimal" VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(app)
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
```

src/app/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(minimal main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(minimal PUBLIC
  lib1_obj 
  lib2_obj
  )
# set install directories
install(TARGETS minimal RUNTIME DESTINATION ~/.local/bin)
```

src/app/main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
  {
  identity_a("main");
  identity_b("main");
  return 0;
  }
```

src/lib1/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib1_obj OBJECT 
  a.cpp 
  )
target_include_directories(lib1_obj PUBLIC .)
```

src/lib1/a.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

void identity_a(const char* caller)
  {
  printf("This is identity_a called from %s.\n", caller);
  }
```

src/lib2//CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib2_obj OBJECT 
  b.cpp 
  )
target_include_directories(lib2_obj PUBLIC .)
```

src/lib/b.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

void identity_b(const char* caller)
  {
  printf("This is identity_b called from %s.\n", caller);
  identity_a("identity_b");
  }
```

Guidance appreciated!